# Athenahealth Sandbox - No module named 'athenahealthapi'

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip

I'm trying to play with sandbox on athenahealth - https://docs.athenahealth.com/api/guides/explore-and-prototype - After registering and creating an application, I begin using sandbox - **try sandbox**. I scroll to the sample code, go to GH >> samplecode >> python3 >> testing.py. When pulling this and running this code I continuously get error

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'athenahealthapi'

I am unable to install athenahealthapi

Comment: You most likely need to locate their `athenahealthapi` on the API website, download, and install it locally. I would imagine they are the only place that hosts the download.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at the API code samples you should see one that has a class connection called APIConnection. I believe you need to save that code as a file named athenahealthapi.py in the same folder that you are running your script. That essentially is the athenahealthapi module and it pulls the APIConnection class as athenahealthapi.APIConnection(). I got past that part but am now having trouble with a missing access_token key error. :(